# divide width evenly between child with hidden overflow x and scroll y and a preview div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want `.content` to scroll vertically and hide it's horizontal overflow, `.preview` and `.editor` should share the parent's width evenly.

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  background: gray;
}

.content {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.editor textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  resize: none;
}

.editor {
  flex: 1;
}

.preview {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='editor'>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class='preview'>
    <div class='content'>
      LongcontentLongcontentLongcontent
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some bad news for you:

> Note: The overflow property only works for block elements with a specified height.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

The 50% issue is caused by box-sizing and default styling of text-area elements; it is overflowing its `.editor` container, making it look larger than 50%;

Here is some code to do what I believe you're trying to do:

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  background: gray;
}

.content {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
/* without specifying a height, the content will never scroll vertically when using overflow-y:auto, because it will continue to grow to it's content's height otherwise */
  max-height: 150px;
}

.editor textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  resize: none;
  box-sizing:border-box; /* prevents drawing outside it's parent */
}
/* without forcing 50% width, flex will let a container's content grow to its content's size. Try with/without */
.editor, .preview {width: 50%}

.editor {
  flex: 1;
}

.preview {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='editor'>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class='preview'>
    <div class='content'>
      THISCONTENTGETSCUTOFF_X_LongcontentLongcontentLongcontentLongcontentLongcontentLongcontentLongcontentLongcontentLongcontent

THIS CONTENT WRAPS AND SCROLLS 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ac fermentum nunc. In vestibulum suscipit quam, ac mattis velit convallis quis. Phasellus ut justo id nunc placerat varius. Curabitur feugiat vulputate facilisis. Nulla est leo, posuere aliquet ligula at, ultricies placerat felis. Curabitur nec tincidunt arcu, sit amet varius nunc. Cras varius risus a tellus auctor egestas. Pellentesque sagittis tortor ac massa facilisis porta. Proin arcu nisl, facilisis non orci ut, tempor tincidunt arcu. Aenean luctus lacinia sapien, at sagittis enim pharetra non. Phasellus blandit pharetra hendrerit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Aliquam at feugiat diam, ut porttitor quam.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But overflow-y puts scrollbars on content as I want. I want content to have width, height of it's parent.

Comment: If you want the `.content` div to scroll when its contents grows larger than the page, you still need to set SOME element's vertical height, up the DOM tree. You could have the `.wrap` have a `max-height: 100vh` or something and set `.content{height: 100%}`, but SOMETHING has to have a height set or it will always be the full content height.